# xcode 4.5 scroll on image wont work

Tags: uiscrollview, uiimageview, xcode4.5

I implemented a zoom on a picture which works just fine. It just wont scroll.

One thing to mention, I try to center the picture but that doesnt work either. Below is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"family.jpeg"];
    self.imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageview];

    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2) - (image.size.width/2), (self.view.frame.size.height / 2) - (image.size.height / 2), image.size.width, image.size.height)];

    [self.scroller setContentSize:[image size]];
    [self.scroller setMaximumZoomScale:2.0];

}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    return self.imageview;
}
```

Thanks very much for whatever help/comment you can provide:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For scrolling, the scrollview contentsize must be greater than the scrollview framesize. You just try this and see if it is scrolling.

[self.scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scroller.frame.size.width+500, self.scroller.frame.size.height+500)];

If it is working, then your image size may be less than the frame size of your scrollview.

Comment: thank you so much for getting back to me. I was able to get it to work using the first tutorial "Scrolling and Zooming a Large image". Though for completeness and to close the loop your method worked as well. I thought I would share this tutorial as it covers alot on scrollviews and images. Having said that, it seems that the tutorial is best if you are using storyboards. I am using a xib file, zooming/scrolling work great but I am unable to center the image for some reason. When I implement it using storyboards only it works great! Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: EDIT: The tutorial is under the following link: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content
if anyone knows why and how to get the images to center in xib files please share your knowledge. Thanks guys.